# Pass id from controller index to store - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

**This is my route :**

```
Route::post('/store', 'EditlinkController@store');
```

**My controller**

```
public function index()
{  
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $links = DB::table('slugs')->where('slugs.id',$id)
             ->join('links','links.sid','=','slugs.id') 
             ->get();  
    return view('editlink', ['links' => $links]);   
}

public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    $url = $request->input('url');

    $data =new link;
    $sid = $id; 
    $data->sid = $sid;
    $data ->url = $url; 
    $data ->save(); 

    return redirect('/links');
}
```

**And my view:**

```html
<form role="form" method='POST' action="{{url('store')}}">
  <div class="entry input-group col-xs-3">
    <input class="form-control" name="url" type='url' placeholder="https://..." size="100"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="_Token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
      <span class="material-icons md-12">add</span>
    </button>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
  </div> 
</form>
```

So basically here I want to call $id from index to store. I also have tried

```
Route::post('/store/{id}', 'EditlinkController@store');
```

But still doesn't work. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your route, `/store/{id}`, requires you to have a route parameter.  Make sure you have an `$id` available to you before you generate your url for your form.

An example of what your open form tag should look like with the `$id` included:

```
<form role="form" method='POST' action="{{url('store', $id)}}">
```

I'm assuming the view **editlink** is where the markup for the form resides. If so, then you can simply pass the value of the id to your view from your controller:

```
return view('editlink', ['links' => $links, 'id' => $id]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works like miracle! And for my case I need to change from POST to GET. Hope it will be useful for everyone. 